# Three.js how to enable VR stereoscopic mode

Tags: three.js, aframe, virtual-reality

Does anyone know a relatively easy implementation to get that split-screen stereoscopic VR view loaded with three.js? I've been searching all over the place and a lot of the implementations seem messy/confusing. If anyone has a good code example they could provide I would really appreciate it. Also, side note I'm trying to avoid using ES6 imports/exports  [image: steroscopic VR example]

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What’s wrong with using aframe and press VR button? If I misunderstood your question, please be more precise.

Comment: I think the problem I'm seeing is that when you enable VR mode in A-Frame it still renders the stereo barrel view but there is no true 3d. It seems flat like it rendering with no offset for each eye. Even the demos on the website seem flat though rendering 360 but no depth. WebXr with just plain Three.js seems to render in true stereo with an offset for each eye.  It seems strange that A-Frame does not have it set as default to render with 3d in VR mode. Moon Rider has true 3d.